# Navigation keys are not working inside cellrenderer input boxes in ag grid

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid

I am having an autocomplete input box inside the cell renderer component in an ag grid cell. whenever i try to press navigation left/right keys it is not moving inside the input suddenly it comes out of the cell. And navigation down/up are used to select the dropdown in the autocomplete it is also not working because of the same problem. anyone help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: use can use `suppressKeyboardEvent` property of `ColDef`. BTW, why are you using `Autocomplete` input box inside `cellRenderer`? Shouldn't you use `cellEditor` if you want to edit value of the cell? Reproduce the issue on plunk or stackblitz for detailed solution.

Comment: I am placing an autocomplete input box and button both inside an cell so that i am using cellRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`suppressKeyboardEvent: params => true` on column definition , if you want all columns then you can use in defaultColDef.
for example

```
const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
        return {
            suppressKeyboardEvent: params => true
        };
    }, []);
```